# Why use the plural form for a single person?

Tags: grammatical-number

Being a non-English native, I'm surprised when I read people who use a plural form when they're clearly talking about a single person.

Here are two excerpts from a software I used to work on, written by a former Irish co-worker:

> ... a supervisor must assign it to **themselves** and deal with it.

and:

> This supervisor has no restaurants assigned to **them**.

I would have written the following sentences instead:

> ... a supervisor must assign it to **himself** and deal with it.

and:

> This supervisor has no restaurants assigned to **him**.

**Is the plural form correct English**, and if so, **is the plural preferred over the singular form?**

Comment: Since both examples deal with "business" there's the issue of gender neutrality in play. Corporate environments can be very picky about that kind of thing.

Comment: Ah yeah, it didn't strike me that this was a gender-neutral thing. Extensive reading indeed in the link @FumbleFingers provides!

Comment: [Everybody has their own opinion about singular _they_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf), but there are in fact rules one can follow.

Comment: @John Lawler   What about this?  A friend of mine calls me up and tells me she is sending a co-worker to hand me a parcel.  Five hours later she calls me again to learn whether the parcel has been delivered:  "I've sent my co-worker, Jan, to deliver the parcel. Have you got it?"  To this point in time, I don't know whether Jan is a male or a female and I tell her: "Jan was here while I was in the shower and left a note saying **they** will be back tomorrow."   Here I don't know who Jan is and I presume I won't be wrong if I consider Jan non-referential.  Would I be wrong?

Comment: @JohnLawler - do you see any sign that 'they' is becoming more used as in this version of your sentence: *A certain Jan (unknown gender) called by and said they'll call back later.*

Comment: Given that you didn't see Jan and only use the name because of the question context, I'd say you're right.

Comment: @Centaurus - er, jinx!!

Comment: @Dan: I don't know; I don't keep track of frequency. You should ask a sociolinguist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) is widely used as a gender-neutral pronoun to refer to a single person.

> A reason for its use is that English has no dedicated singular personal pronoun of indeterminate gender.<sup>[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#CITEREFGarner2003)</sup> In some cases, its use can be explained by notional agreement because words like "everyone", though singular in form, are plural in meaning.<sup>[[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#CITEREFGarner2003)</sup> Its use in formal English has increased in recent times with the trend toward gender-inclusive language,<sup>[[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#CITEREFHuddlestonPullum2002)</sup> but it has been used by respected writers for centuries.<sup>[[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#CITEREFMerriam-Webster2002)</sup>
>
> Though singular "they" has a long history of usage and is common in everyday English, its use has been criticized since the late nineteenth century, and acceptance varies.